# Is there a package or canonical way for writing test harnesses in Mathematica?

Tags: debugging, development

I've written a complicated function `foo`.<sup>1</sup>

I'd now like to simplify this function's code, and later enhance it with more features. With each change, however, I'd like to be confident that I'm not breaking previously met specifications. So, I'm looking for a test harness to run between each change.

The obvious, "poor man's" way of doing this seems to be to write a series of `If[...]` statements that check a given piece of code against expected output, and `Print` messages according to the results. Or, I could get fancier, specify my tests in a table, for example—

[image]

—and automate the testing. (If I were to continue down this route, then of course I'd have to `Hold@` the entire table to prevent cells from executing, and write a function that `Extract`s each row in turn, running the expression and checking its return value.)

But, I'm wondering if there's a package in $Mathematica$ built for this purpose, or at least some canonical way of doing things that I should start getting used to, especially if I'm heading toward writing larger and larger pieces of code, maybe even packages and applications, eventually.

Googling <kbd>Mathematica</kbd> <kbd>test</kbd> <kbd>harness</kbd>, I've come across some pages about *MUnit*, which appear specific to Workbench, which I don't have.

<sup><sup>1</sup> In case it'd be helpful to know, my `foo` is essentially a data wrapper. Given a symbol, it copies the symbol's OwnValue elsewhere, unsets the symbol, then redefines that symbol with DownValues and UpValues.</sup>

Comment: Other than *Workbench* functionality, I'm not aware of any. I use the `Assert` function much when testing though...