# Perform localized, evaluation-leak free replacements

Tags: evaluation, replacement, hold

Consider the following expression:

```
expr = Hold[
   {
    f[
     {1, {Print@1}}
     ],
    g[
     {{{Print@1}}}
     ]
    }
   ];
```

I'm looking for a way to apply a replacement rule to the contents of all expressions with head `f`. To give a more concrete example, let's say I want to replace `Print` by `Echo`, but only inside `f`.

**Restrictions**: I have no knowledge about the exact structure around and inside `f` - there could be more or less nesting going on. This means the replacement rule can't capture the wrapper with `Hold` attribute, nor can it capture the individual parts of `f[…]`. (And the evaluation of `Print` should be prevented of course)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a way making use of `Block` to cause `f` to be inert:

```
Block[{f},
 SetAttributes[f, HoldAllComplete];
 expr /. f[args__] :>
   RuleCondition[f[args] /. Print -> Echo]
 ]

Hold[{f[{1, {Echo[1]}}], g[{{{Print[1]}}}]}]
```

Note of course that this only works if you have a pattern of the form `_Symbol[...]`

Answer (score 8):

[Edit: For most situations, [@Kuba's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/188953/36508) is better]

I can think of one (ugly) way to do it:

```
Attributes[myHold] = {HoldAll};

expr /.
 f[args__] :> With[
   {res = myHold[args] /. Print -> Echo},
   f @@ res /; True
 ] /.
  HoldPattern[f_ @@ myHold[args__]] :> f[args]
(* Hold[{f[{1, {Echo[1]}}], g[{{{Print[1]}}}]}] *)
```

The idea is to wrap the contents of `f` inside a function with `HoldAll` attribute (not `Hold`, to be able to identify it uniquely later on). In a first step, the expression is returned with `myHold[…]` still in place. In a second round of replacements, `myHold` is stripped out again.

Comment: +1.  If we use the _vanishing_ macro defined in [(43096)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43096/142), we can write `vanishing[{h}, expr /. x_f :> RuleCondition[h[x] /. Print -> Echo]]`.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively:

```
expr /. 
  foo_f :> RuleCondition[Hold[foo] /. Print -> Echo] /. 
  Hold[foo_f] :> foo
```

We can safely perform the second replacement because we just wrapped every `f[..]` with `Hold`.

Comment: +1 - In general, this is definitely better than my solution - the only potential issue is the fact that the pattern `_f` has to be written twice - so for complex patterns, this might lead to some code-duplication/performance cost

Comment: @LukasLang yes, consider this a quick solution to a specific problem. In general something like b3m2a1 shows is needed or a dummy vanishing head.