# Is there a way to "hold" prefix / infix / postfix notation?

Tags: formatting, custom-notation, style

Is it possible to preserve a specific style of notation in $Mathematica$ output?

```
foo // bar
(* bar[foo] *)

Hold[foo // bar]
(* bar[foo] *)
```

I'm writing some code that generates sample code (*e.g.* a usage hint), and in one case I feel that postfix notation is easier on the eyes. I know it's subjective and not that important but now I'm just curious whether this is possible to control.

---

### Edit

`Postfix` preserves the notation as @rasher pointed out. However, my intent was to allow convenient evaluation of sample code by being able to immediately evaluate the output—that is, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> the `foo//bar`. When `Postfix` is the head of an expression though, the evaluation simply returns the expression—which, makes complete sense, since that's what `Postfix`... does. (This question almost seems circular now.)

Is there a way, perhaps, to create a custom `PostfixToEvaluate` head that would *display* the expression in postfix but, maybe via an UpValue, remove itself and evaluate its contents, upon evaluation? (I don't know if that makes any sense. I'm going to try it now...)

---

<sup>Tags I considered but don't believe are relevant: [stylesheet](/questions/tagged/stylesheet) [hold](/questions/tagged/hold) [expression-manipulation](/questions/tagged/expression-manipulation). Note that I've left "hold" in the title as that's the intuitive keyword by which I would have searched, were I a future visitor.</sup>

Comment: Am I missing something in the question? `Postfix[foo//bar]` will output `foo//bar`?

Comment: @rasher — Nope... that's it. Sorry, I viewed this as a _notational_ issue more than a _coding_ one, and didn't even imagine there'd be functions for manipulating notations, _e.g._ `Postfix`. Thank you. Would you post it as an answer? (Though, I expect this question to get closed or deleted.) It wasn't very obvious to me, at least.

Comment: No worries, sure, I'll post it, and I'd be surprised if closed, it's in the somewhat obscure area... you ask interesting questions!

Comment: You could perhaps do as something like `Interpretation["2//Sqrt//N", 2 // Sqrt // N]`. This displays as the string, when shift-entered, it evaluates as expected. Downside is it leaves the original, but quotes it (might not be such a bad thing). You could, I suppose, add the notebook commands to go up one and delete that as part of eval...

Comment: Perhaps some progress... `Interpretation[Style["2//Sqrt//N", ShowStringCharacters -> False], 
 2 // Sqrt // N]` will show as the string, when evaluated, evaluates as expected, turns into typical bold MMA input form when done with no quotes, can be re-evaluated as often as wanted...

Comment: @rasher — Clever, thanks! However, my actual expression to be postfixed is involves input in `TableForm` (check back [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43014/is-there-a-package-or-canonical-way-for-writing-test-harnesses-in-mathematica) at a later date; I plan to self-answer), so I'm afraid that depending on a string representation might fail. (I recently stumbled across a solution that works, though! Typing it out now.) Thanks for your help thus far.

Answer (score 2):

As requested:

```
Postfix[foo//bar]
```

will output

```
foo//bar
```

And as you noted in the comment reply, there are equivalents for infix and prefix. `Format` might also be of interest...

Comment: Hm, I encountered an issue, actually. (Sorry to unaccept!) My intent was to generate an output cell in postfix notation that would, conveniently, evaluate on Shift+Enter. Unfortunately, the `Postfix` head remains upon attempting to evaluate. I wonder how I can generate output in Postfix notation that would vanish the `Postfix` and evaluate its contents upon evaluation?

Comment: No worry, your original question implied you were interested in the output only. I'll poke around when time permits.

Comment: Does `Interpretation[Postfix[foo // bar], foo // bar]` work?

Comment: @SimonWoods: Only when foo/bar evaluate to themselves, hence by use of strings in my comment to OP. OP says they've got a working way, my curiosity has been whetted...Using `Interpretation` is pretty cool though, since I can display *anything*, valid or not, manipulate as I please, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This may be unhelpful but motivate. Assuming the purpose is education you could use:

```
ntn[u_] := 
 FlipView[{Style[u, 20], 
   Row[{Style[ToExpression[u], 20]}, Background -> LightRed]}]
```

Examples (in gif):

[image]

Comment: Interesting! Unfortunately my actual expression involves input in `TableForm` (see comments on question), so I'm afraid a string representation may fail. Thank you for your input however.

Comment: @acheong87 apologies. Perhaps some approach, e.g. you could use`EventHandler` or other dynamic approach to achieve your aim

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on what you're looking for here, but perhaps the following is close. First, I assume you don't want everything in postfix because you mention "in one case I feel that postfix notation is easier on the eyes". So, rather than creating a wrapper that makes everything postfix, I will instead modify the formatting of the function `bar` so that it is displayed in postfix:

```
bar /: MakeBoxes[bar[foo_], StandardForm] := RowBox[{MakeBoxes[foo], "//", "bar"}]
```

Let's also give `bar` a down value:

```
bar[x_] := x^2
```

Then, you can create a table using [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer):

```
table = TableForm[
    {
    {Plus, a+b},
    {Subtract, a-b},
    {bar, Defer[a //bar]}
    },
    TableHeadings->{"function", "example"}
]
```

[image]

Evaluating the above [`TableForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableForm) object yields:

{{Plus, a + b}, {Subtract, a - b}, {bar, a^2}}