# Stopping a head from evaluating more than once

Tags: evaluation, symbols, hold

While attempting to answer my own question, [Is there a way to "hold" prefix / infix / postfix notation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43168/is-there-a-way-to-hold-prefix-infix-postfix-notation), I came across the need to evaluate a recursive function only one level deep.

For example, consider a factorial function:

```
factorial[n_Integer /; n >= 0] := If[n >= 2, n*factorial[n - 1], 1]
```

Normally, expressions using `factorial` would be fully evaluated:

```
2 + 3*(factorial[5] + factorial[7])
(* 15482 *)
```

However, is there a way to evaluate `factorial` just once, and prevent evaluating any further occurrences? That is, a function, `EvaluateHeadOnce`:

```
EvaluateHeadOnce[factorial, 2 + 3*(factorial[5] + factorial[7])]
(* 2 + 3 (5 factorial[4] + factorial[7]) *)
```

I found a method (self-answered below) but it felt rather... inelegant. I'm curious to see how others would implement such a method, as well as hear criticisms / flaws in my approach.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: [How do I evaluate only one step of an expression?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/334/5)

Comment: Apologies for failing to give due credit—@Mr.Wizard's answer in that thread is where I got the `TraceScan` idea. However, unless I'm mistaken, a "step" in the context of that question is different from that of mine. In mine, I'm looking to evaluate as many steps as needed, until the _second_ instance of a specified head is encountered.

Answer (score 5):

If I understood your requirements correctly, what you need is [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Defer.html), which is in the same class of functions as `Hold` and `Unevaluated`, but will evaluate if explicitly evaluated. Then, using Trott–Strzebonski:

```
Clear@factorial
factorial[n_Integer /; n >= 0] := With[{m = n - 1}, If[n >= 2, n*Defer@factorial[m], 1]]
factorial[0] = 0;
```

[image]

(In the lines after `In[4]`, the previous output was explicitly evaluated using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Comment: Brilliant! I can't believe I didn't come across `Defer` while doing my research (sigh). To be pedantic, I was looking for a function `EvaluateHeadOnce` that could be applied to any existing function `f`, the way Mr. Wizard's `step` can be applied to any expression, but that's only a matter of reorganizing your code to an appropriate form, so no need to update it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Version 10 will have a new evaluation control called [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) (and a corresponding `Activate`). With that, you can easily wrap a desired head in the recursive expression with [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) and every successive `Activate` will effectively evaluate one step. That might provide slightly better control than `Defer`, which requires an explicit evaluation. You can also mimic the functionality of `Inactive` and `Activate` in v9 with custom functions and appropriate attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I could come up with was to use [`TraceScan`](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TraceScan.html) to detect the first evaluation of the symbol, at which point I'd [copy the symbol (including all its UpValues, DownValues, etc.)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19902/copying-one-symbol-into-another) to a temporary place, unset the symbol to prevent further evaluation, and set [`$Pre`](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$Pre.html) to restore the symbol immediately prior to evaluating the next input (as well as unsetting `$Pre` itself).

```
MoveSymbol[old_, new_] := (
   Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[new] = 
     Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[old] /. HoldPattern[old] :> new;
   ClearAll[old];
   );
SetAttributes[EvaluateHeadOnce, HoldAll];
EvaluateHeadOnce[head_Symbol, expr_] := Module[{headsFound = 0, copy, resetter},
  TraceScan[
   If[
     headsFound++ == 1,
     MoveSymbol[head, copy];
     SetAttributes[resetter, HoldAll];
     resetter[input_] := (MoveSymbol[copy, head]; $Pre =.; input);
 $Pre = resetter;
     Return[ReleaseHold@#]
     ] &,
   expr,
   head[___]
   ]
  ]
```

This output is, as desired,

```
EvaluateHeadOnce[factorial, 2 + 3*(factorial[5] + factorial[7])]
(* 2 + 3 (5 factorial[4] + factorial[7]) *)
```

and of course, may continue,

```
EvaluateHeadOnce[factorial, %]
(* 2 + 3 (20 factorial[3] + factorial[7]) *)
```

But, might there be a more elegant method?

I was going to extend the above to take a list of symbols rather than a specific one, but I've decided to wait in case one of the $Mathematica$ veterans show up and put my answer to shame.